# Blackberry app: Drop marker to get latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I'd like to have a page on my Blackberry app where the user can drop a marker on a map (Google map most likely) and the coordinates (latitude and longitude) of the marker will be retrieved.

I have looked into the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) but this returns an image, with no option for placing markers and getting their coordinates back from Google.

I also looked at getting the coordinates of a point on a static map from the pixel locations [look here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=455491), but this is very involved and the different screen sizes of Blackberry phones will each need different calculations.

What I want to do seems easily done [in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726049/how-do-you-click-on-a-map-and-have-latitude-and-longitude-fields-in-a-form-popul) using the Google Javascript API and also Google Maps for iOS or Android, but no Web service that returns a clickable map.

EDIT: I am developing the app for Blackberry OS version 4.5, or 5.0 if necessary.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 2):

1. Try this map code as hml file
2. invoke html file into qml using `Webview{}`

**Drop Maker**

```
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      });
```

---

**Google Map Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(13.052414,80.250825);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:12,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```