# Fetch longitude and latitude google map

Tags: dictionary

I'have my google map v3 with geolocalisation no problem !

But I would like fetch longitude and latitude to my forms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Google markers for it. Here is whole documentation to it. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

If I understand your question correctly, This is related to what you are looking for: [How do you click on a map and have latitude and longitude fields in a form populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726049/how-do-you-click-on-a-map-and-have-latitude-and-longitude-fields-in-a-form-popul)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you need latitude and longitude everywhere you move you mouse you can do it like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove', function(event) {
    console.log(event.latLng);
$("#inputFormLat").val(event.latlng.lat()); //your input text box (i used jquery here to select it and set its value)
$("#inputFormLon").val(event.latlng.lng());

});
```

If you have any doubt pls ask

Regards, 
Suyash

Answer (score 0):

If you need long/lat coordinates for a polygon or a single point here is a useful tool: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/ujdgK)

**JS**

```
var bermudaTriangle;
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.5190755, -111.9253654);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.RoadMap
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.5362475, -111.9267386),
        new google.maps.LatLng(33.5104882, -111.9627875),
        new google.maps.LatLng(33.5004686, -111.9027061)

  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    draggable: true,
    editable: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, "dragend", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), "insert_at", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), "remove_at", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), "set_at", getPolygonCoords);
}

function getPolygonCoords() {
  var len = bermudaTriangle.getPath().getLength();
  var htmlStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    htmlStr += bermudaTriangle.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(5) + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```